# Obtener valores de objeto Rest JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest

Hago una peticion con Ajax a un web service y este me decuelve un objeto.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=*******"
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

En la consola me aparece el objeto que tiene una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
{"Meta Data":{"1. Information":"Intraday (1min) prices and volumes","2. Symbol":"MSFT","3. Last Refreshed":"2018-05-30 16:00:00","4. Interval":"1min","5. Output Size":"Compact","6. Time Zone":"US/Eastern"},"Time Series (1min)":{"2018-05-30 16:00:00":{"1. open":"99.0000","2. high":"99.0500","3. low":"98.9100","4. close":"98.9500","5. volume":"2233252"}, ......
```

El tema es que no se como acceder por ejemplo al valor del campo open":"99.0000"

¿Que deberia de hacer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para acceder a objetos json simplemente tienes que seguir su estructura con ".", te lo explico con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
data ={"fecha":{"fechaInicio:"20/02/2017","fechaFin":"20/05/2018"}}
```

Para acceder a `fechaFin` deberias hacer:

```
console.log(data.fecha.fechaFin)
```

Como las `id` de tu objeto tienen espacio puedes usar este otro metodo para acceder a los valores:

```
console.log(data["fecha"]["fechaFin"]);
```

Por lo tanto para acceder al dato que tu deseas, siguiendo la estructura que has pasado deberías usar el segundo método:

```
data["Time Series (1min)"]["2018-05-30 16:00:00"]["1. open"]
```

Comment: Genial me sirvio. Gracias !!!!